# Android How to have two different version of my application

Tags: android, apk, crashlytics

I'd like to know if there is a way to have two version of our application on the same device.

The purpose is to have the one using our production api to use it normally while having one we could deploy inside our team using our test api without having to uninstall the production one?

We are deploying production through the playstore and for the moment we are using Crashlytics to deploy in intern. If we could keep using this tools it would be great.

If you have any idea?

Regards,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075699/how-to-keep-two-versions-of-the-same-android-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use build variant in android studio.
Go project architecture and add flavor and set diifrent value according to need
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a way to do this i.e. product flavors. [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) is the android guide lines for this purpose.